# PowerShell Scripts

Tags: list, powershell, visual-studio

Does anybody know if there's some way to delete items from an SPList using PowerShell scripting?

If is this possible, has anybody any good tutorial?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

Since you can access the object model it's pretty straight forward

```
asnp microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb http://thesite/
$list = $web.Lists["NameOfList"]
$item = $list.GetItemById(1) 
$item.Delete()
```

Comment: ok. now,  should I just save it as .ps and then run it from  PS??

Comment: You just open a new powershell session and write the code...and yes, you could make it into a .ps1 script file if you need...

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://mysharepointwork.blogspot.com/2010/09/addupdatedelete-list-items-using.html)'s the example.

**Quote from link:**

Delete Item -

The example below will count the items and loop down, read the name of the item, and if the item contains a 3, then it will delete that item.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://test.tomdaly.com") # is a legit url
$relweburl = "/Docs"
$web = $site.openweb($relweburl)
$list=$web.Lists["testList"] $listItems = $list.Items
$listItemsTotal = $listItems.Count

for ($x=$listItemsTotal-1;$x -ge 0; $x--)
{
    if($listItems[$x].name.Contains("3"))
    {
        Write-Host("DELETED: " + $listItems[$x].name)
        $listItems[$x].Delete()
    }
}
```